# Entity Framework - Using stored procedure which return same column names from different entities

Tags: entity-framework, complextype

I have tables named Contact and Address and both of them have "ModifiedDate" column. I have written the CUD operations using Stored procedures. However, when It came to SELECT stored procedure in which I needed to return all the contacts with their addresses, I got an error.

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException:
>   The data reader is incompatible with
>   the specified
>   'AddressBookModel.SelectAllContactsWithAddresses_Result2'.
>   A member of the type, 'ModifiedDate1',
>   does not have a corresponding column
>   in the data reader with the same name.

I ended up changing the stored procedure to return different aliases for those column name and more unfortunately, I needed to change the properties in the entities in the model as well to match the selected column. I wrote a blog post about this [here](http://ashishrocks.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!BED6CE34F24CB429!538.entry?&_c02_vws=1). **I know I could have separate select SPs (and separate function imports) for both the entities** but this is just one situation and can happen in other cases as well where same columns names might get returned from a complex query from multiple tables in a SP. Could anybody provide any direction on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question in the MS forums for EF [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/693af8f5-4302-49f4-826a-528f8490abdc/) (sorry for the cross posting) and the moderator confirmed that this is a bug in EF and asked me to create a bug in the Microsoft Connect and the bug Id is 597376 and here is the [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/597376/using-stored-procedure-which-return-same-column-names-from-different-entities) for the same.

from Lingzhi Sun
MSFT, Moderator
Support in Forum>

```
Hello,   After some research and test,
> I can repro this issue at my side.  
> It can be a limitation of EF when
> handling stored procedure return
> values.  I would recommend you open a
> ticket at Microsoft Connect to report
> this issue to the product team.   If
> it is convenient, please share us with
> the ticket link here to benefit more
> community members.
```